# Solving a system of second order PDEs using Runge Kutta in C

Tags: c, system, pde, runge-kutta

I have a problem solving a system of differential equations using the Runge Kutta algorithm. So far I have rewritten the second order PDE into a set of two coupled equations where

```
    f(L1,L2) = L2
    g(L1,L2) = A*(B*L1-C*L2-D)
```

are the two equations and A, B, C and D are constants.
In order to get the value for the next step, I proceeded as follows for each time step dt:

```
    k1 = f(L1,L2)
    l1 = g(L1,L2)

    k2 = f(L1 + 0.5 * dt * k1,L2 + 0.5 * dt * l1 )
    l2 = g(L1 + 0.5 * dt * k1,L2 + 0.5 * dt * l1 )

    k3 = f(L1 + 0.5 * dt * k2,L2 + 0.5 * dt * l2 )
    l3 = g(L1 + 0.5 * dt * k2, L2 + 0.5 * dt * l2 )

    k4 = f(L1 + dt * k1,L2 +  dt * l1 )
    l4 = g(L1 + dt * k1,L2 + dt * l1 )
```

Where I use the values for L1 and L2 of the current time step and calculate the coefficients iteratively.

As a result I get L1 and L2 by summing up and weighting the coefficients at the end.
My problem is, that the whole algorithm becomes unstable after 4 time steps.

Does anybody know if the realization is technically correct?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show L1 and L2 please?

Comment: L1 and L2 are values. for the first step, I used the starting values here.

Comment: And by *values* you mean constants, right? What starting values do you use? Can you show the output of your integration for a couple of steps?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, since you don't say what `dt` value you use: keep it small as possible, because

> local truncation error is on the order of O(h^5), while the total accumulated error is order O(h^4).

(cited from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) wikipedia article, dt plays the h role).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that it does not depend on dt (time inkrement) in my case. There is no big difference in the values if I put dt=0.001 or 0.01. That is why I think it is wrong...My question is, if that is the correct way to implement Runge Kutta since I have no idea how to test it differently...

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Runge-Kutta *in general* is not stable. It is just "more stable" than Euler's. Depending on the *condition* of your differential equation and the  `dt` it might just not be sufficient. Does a smaller `dt` help?

I'm missing the notion of `t` in your definition of `f` and `g`. Assuming `L1` and `L2` are not constant in `t` you better pass it through `f` and `g`. Like `f(t,L1,L2)`. This forces you to think about those coefficient calculations, where you now need to pass another `t'` accordingly. This will lead to the evaluation of L1 and L2 at midpoints.

Answer (score 0):

In the computation of `k4, l4` you used `k1, l1` to compute the state where the ODE function is evaluated, while the method demands to use `k3, l3`. This error will reduce the order of the method, probably to 2, and the dependence of the error on the step size will reflect that.